# Gitlab CI: multi-project pipelines trigger doesnt run the latest commit of downstream branch on re-run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I currently have a successfully established multi-project pipelines which triggers a downstream pipeline in my "Project B" when I run "Project A" pipeline.

Below is my `gitlab-ci.yml` of my upstream "Project A".

```
...

browser-test:
  stage: integration-test
  trigger:
    project: path/to/projectB
    branch: develop
    strategy: depend

...
```

**Issue I'm facing**

When A's CI expectedly fails due to outdated tests, I fix & update B's develop branch and re-run A's CI **expecting the upstream CI to now trigger the latest fixed commit of B's develop branch** but unfortunately it triggers the downstream pipeline with the old commit (not the latest commit I made) which obviously fails again.

Comment: A workaround could be manually creating a new pipeline instead of rerunning the failed one.

Comment: @GerardGarcia - true but isnt rerunning supposed to trigger the latest anyway ?